# exporting Listboxes To Excel

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, listbox

I'm trying to export 3 listboxes into excel file .
each listbox must export to different cell.

there is no error when debugging .
but it's not working and making the form freeze.

here is my code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  Handles  Button1.Click
    MsExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    MsExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\11.xlsx")

    OffS = 0

    For Each oItem In ListBox1.Items

        MsExcel.Range("AB2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItem

        OffS = OffS + 1

        For Each oItemm In ListBox2.Items

            MsExcel.Range("AC2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItemm

            OffS = OffS + 1

            For Each oItemmm In ListBox3.Items

                MsExcel.Range("AD2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItemmm

                OffS = OffS + 1

            Next oItemmm

        Next oItemm

    Next oItem

    MsExcel.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to un-nest the loops! 
In your code, the loop for ListBox2 would execute for each item in ListBox1, and worst for ListBox3!

And be careful, if you nest loops, you'll need different controls/index (here you have the same variable for the 3 nested loops)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  Handles  Button1.Click
MsExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
MsExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\11.xlsx")

OffS = 0
For Each oItem In ListBox1.Items
    MsExcel.Range("AB2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItem
    OffS = OffS + 1
Next oItem

OffS = 0
For Each oItemm In ListBox2.Items
    MsExcel.Range("AC2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItemm
    OffS = OffS + 1
Next oItemm

OffS = 0
For Each oItemmm In ListBox3.Items
    MsExcel.Range("AD2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItemmm
    OffS = OffS + 1
Next oItemmm

MsExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```